# Summation by parts on martingales?

Tags: probability-theory, summation, stochastic-processes

Finding $\int (X_s^{-} dY)=\sum_{k=1}^{k=n } X_{k-1}(Y_k -Y_{k-1})$
Where $X_s$ and  $Y$ are semi-martingale.
Expanding this by summation by parts gives $$\sum_{k=1}^{k=n } x_{k-1}(y_k -y_{k-1})=x_n y_n-x_0y_0 -\sum_{k=1}^{k=n } y_{k-1}(x_k -x_{k-1}) $$
but the evaluation in the book is  $$\sum_{k=1}^{k=n } x_{k-1}(y_k - y_{k-1})=x_n y_n- x_0y_0 -\sum_{k=1}^{k=n } y_{k-1}(x_k -x_{k-1})-\sum_{k=1}^{k=n } y_{k-1}(x_k -x_{k-1})-\sum_{k=1}^{k=n} (y_{k}-y_{k-1})(x_k -x_{k-1}).$$
Can anyone explain why the extra term  $\sum_{k=1}^{k=n} (y_{k}-y_{k-1})(x_k -x_{k-1})$ comes up?

Comment: @saz can you explain it

Comment: Please verify it $n=1$, which one is reasonable

Answer (score 0):

The formula in the book is wrong, however, I know where this is coming from.

If we expand the multiple of differences, we get the formula
$$(y_k-y_{k-1})(x_k-x_{k-1})=y_k(x_k-x_{k-1})-y_{k-1}(x_k-x_{k-1}).$$
Then, by rearranging
$$-y_k(x_k-x_{k-1})=-y_{k-1}(x_k-x_{k-1})-(y_k-y_{k-1})(x_k-x_{k-1}).$$

And thus, from the summation by parts formula
$$\sum_{k=1}^n x_{k-1}(y_k-y_{k-1})=x_{n-1}y_n-x_0y_0-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} y_k(x_k-x_{k-1}),$$
by plugging the above relationship we get the expression
$$\sum_{k=1}^n x_{k-1}(y_k-y_{k-1})=x_{n-1}y_n-x_0y_0-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} y_{k-1}(x_k-x_{k-1})-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (y_k-y_{k-1})(x_k-x_{k-1}).$$